# How to get a web URL for a PullRequest using TFS client libraries?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, pull-request, tfs-sdk

Is there a way to get web URL(TeamWebAccess like `https://tfshost/tfs/Collection/Project/_git/Repository/pullrequest/12345` for PR#12345, not the API url) for a PullRequest using TFS [client libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.112.1)?

```
var prId = 12345;
var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(""));
var git = tpc.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
// GitHttpClient has no special methods to do it
// and GitPullRequest obtained through GitHttpClient.GetPullRequestByIdAsync contains only the API link
var prWebUrl = git.?????(prId);
```

Perhaps there is something analogous to [TswaClientHyperlinkService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff737417(v=vs.120)) that I missed?

Or do I have to resort to deducing web URL from API link/`GitPullRequest` properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not able to get the `RemoteUrl` from the client library direrctly, as the value is `null`. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

But you could get the `RemoteUrl` for a repository (`https://tfshost/tfs/Collection/Project/_git/Repository`), so you can use the following code to get the PR RemoteUrl:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;

namespace GetPullRequest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String collectionUri = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com";
            VssBasicCredential creds = new VssBasicCredential("", "6ztnrtjdd3i42juchu4xxxxxxxxxaslnseo277tgiuiq");
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
            var git = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
            var prId = 12345;
            var pr = git.GetPullRequestByIdAsync(prId).Result;
            var RepoUrl = pr.Repository.RemoteUrl;
            var prUrl = RepoUrl + "/pullrequest/" + prId;
            Console.WriteLine(prUrl);

        }
    }
}
```